# Searching AD with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I need to query an AD to retrieve the groups in the domain and its children domains. When I run the following code, all I get is the current domain groups only, not the ones from the child domain (example: mydomain.com and child.mydomain.com). Do you have any idea on what I'm missing ?

```
using(var filter = new GroupPrincipal(new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)))
{
    filter.IsSecurityGroup = true;
    filter.GroupScope = GroupScope.Global;
    using(var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(filter)
    using(var results = searcher.FindAll())
    {
        //results contains the groups in mydomain.com only
    }
}
```

(updated the code to better describe the calls made)

Comment: Try with the GroupScope Property for GroupPrincipal http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.groupscope.aspx

Comment: I tried and still cannot see my subdomain groups :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [List users in active directory domain AND subdomain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343788/list-users-in-active-directory-domain-and-subdomain)

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343788/list-users-in-active-directory-domain-and-subdomain/18368048#18368048).

You can use the Global Catalog to search the whole forest.

If you only need to search a part of the forest and any subdomains of that domain you can narrow it by specifying the domain base as a starting point.